# Create git server with many repositories

Tags: linux, ssh, git

Please consider my question from a technical point of view. I am faced with the problem of access control to git repositories. I need to somehow distinguish the access of certain ssh-keys. That is, the key should give access to one repository, not to all. I looked at how git servers are organized: a git user is created (that's what it's called, I'm shocked))), a repository (one) is created and shh keys of development participants are added. So, I need this repository to be not one but many, but the key did not give access to all depositories. If you know how such services and products as GitLab, Gitlab, gitlab are organized, I really want to know how to organize access. I will be glad of any comments, questions, answers, thank you in advance for your attention to the question)))

Comment: In such services as gitlab, github this problem is solved, but I can't understand what technical solution(

Comment: there are a few products that allow you to host your own github-like system, e.g. ones that I've personally used are `gogs` and `gitea`

Answer (score 1):

In GitLab you work with projects and project groups, and assign rights to these. The [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/) explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`gitolite`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) project code. It is very simple command-line-only system to manage multiple git repos with multiple users and different access permissions.

It creates a single ssh user `gitolite` with multiple ssh public keys put in `authorized_keys`. It sets `"command=gitolite-shell username"` in `authorized_keys` for each individual ssh public key to call its `gitolite-shell` wrapper for a user. The wrapper then uses gitlite config to determine calling user access rights to each git repo.